# Autofac difference between Register and RegisterType

Tags: autofac

I have started to use Autofac following this tutorials:
http://flexamusements.blogspot.com/2010/09/dependency-injection-part-3-making-our.html

**Simple class with no parameter in the constructor**

```
builder.RegisterType<ConsoleOutputService>().As<IOutputService>();
```

As explained in the tutorial, the code above can be read as: setup ConsoleOutputService as the implementation of IOutputService

**Simple class with one parameter in the constructor**

```
builder.Register(c => new MultipleOutputService(outputFilePath)).As<IOutputService>();
```

I don't understand why are we using a lambda expression to register this class (and what does this expression exactly does) and why we can't type this code

```
builder.RegisterType<MultipleOutputService(outputFilePath)>().As<IOutputService>();
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't write that code because it doesn't make sense in C#.
`RegisterType` is a generic method; generic methods must take *types* as generic parameters.

You're trying to register a type with a custom way to create it (inyour case, a constructor parameter); the only way that C# supports to specify such a thing is a lambda expression (or other delegate).

Answer (score 19):

Btw there is a better solution to this Autofac introduced the `.WithParameter()` extension to their registration builder.

```
.RegisterType<MultipleOutputService>().As<IOutputService>().WithParameter("parameterName", "parameterValue");
```

This should cater for the event that you need to pass something other than an interface type to one of your constructors

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, as it answers ops real question.

Answer (score 5):

The lambda variant enables us to do some logic when constructing the instance.