# Are .Register and .RegisterType equivalent (for classes with parameterless constructors)?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

When using AutoFac, you can use `.RegisterType` to associate a class with an interface, but you can also use `.Register` (which allows you to specify construtor arguments via a lambda).

For classes that have a parameterless constructor, are these two methods equivalent?

```
var builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().As<IMyInterface>();
builder.Register(x => new MyClass()).As<IMyInterface>();
```

Is there any scenario where using `.RegisterType` is perferable?

Comment: Autofac difference between register and registertype http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984426/autofac-difference-between-register-and-registertype

Comment: @Alexandru-DanMaftei Thanks, but that question is different to mine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your class only has one defined constructor, they should be functionally equivalent.

One internal difference would be that `RegisterType` will use reflection to determine that constructor to use while `Register` with a lambda has provided all the information needed.